# Checking boolean variable from JQuery POST in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, boolean

I am new in PHP.

I have a variable in jquery called `editMode` set to `false`. I used `$.post()` in jquery to pass the variable in a php function. But when I check its value, the value is fine, but if statement does not function the way it's supposed to. Here is my code:

jQuery (just a snippet):

```
var editMode = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    //some function that handles UI input that triggers editMode=true

    $("#form").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();

      var fName = $("#firstname").val();
      var lName = $("#lastname").val();
      //... and the rest of post values coming from UI input

      $.post('includes/sql/register.php', {
         fName: fName,
         lName: lName,
         //... and the rest of post values coming from UI input
         editMode: editMode // this is where I post the value for editMode
      },
      //jQuery function to handle the result
});
```

In my register.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $fName = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['fName']);
     $lName = mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lName']);
     //and other post values from UI input
     $editMode = $_POST['editMode'];

     if($editMode) {
        echo $editMode . ": edit"; //fires update query
     } else {
        echo  $editMode . "add"; //fires insert query
     }
  } 
?>
```

When testing the code, it returns the correct value of `$editMode`, but does not perform the if statement correctly. What I mean is, if `$editMode` is true, it echoes: `true: edit`, which is good. But when it's false, it echoes: `false: edit`. So it still performs the `if` clause, even if its value is now `false`. I also tried `if($editMode === true) {//edit} else {//add}`, and it does the opposite. Whether `$editMode` is true or false, it performs the `else` clause. Please enlighten me.

Comment: You can send a flag as 1 for true and 0 for false (instead of `true`/`false` in JavaScript). That becomes `if ("0")` which is false, or `if ("1")` which is true. All POST data are sent as strings (booleans too for some reason, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: That answered it! Can you post this as an answer, so I can mark this as solved. Thanks mate! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All POST requests sent will be treated as strings - and if I'm not mistaken, a boolean value of `true` in JavaScript becomes the *string* of `"true"` in PHP (as it is converted to a sting before being sent to PHP).

I would suggest sending the data as an integer representation of the boolean value, that is doing sending the `editMode` data as `editMode ? 1 : 0`.

```
$.post('includes/sql/register.php', {
    fName: fName,
    lName: lName,
    //... and the rest of post values coming from UI input
    editMode: editMode ? 1 : 0 
},
```

Which in PHP becomes `if ("1")` for true and `if ("0")` for false. Since PHP is a weakly typed language, these will be treated as integers (`if (1)` and `if (0)`) which will be true and false expressions respectively.

So in PHP you can do

```php
if ($editMode) {
    echo "true: edit"; //fires update query
} else {
    echo "false: edit";  //fires insert query
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can validate the boolean value before checking in your conditional statement:

```
$editMode = 'False';
$editMode = filter_var($editMode, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
if ($editMode) {
    echo $editMode . ": edit"; //fires update query
} else {
    echo  $editMode . "add"; //fires insert query
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. I like this answer better, since it "forces" the PHP to treat the variable as boolean, instead of string. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your code as it is just send the false in string

instead of

```
var editMode = false;
```

use

```
var editMode = "false";
```

and in your php file

```
if($editMode == "true") {
```